# Determining in Java whether a particular font can render a particular character

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, character

Is there a way in Java to determine whether a particular font can render a particular character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Font f = ... ; // you have your font
Character c = 'ن'; // Nun, N, in Farsi

if(!f.canDisplay(c)) {
    int gcode = f.getMissingGlyphCode();
    System.out.format("not supported.  Glyph code used: %d\n", gcode);
}
```

Comment: Tested this for JDK Korean + Windows bug and it seems to work! `Font f = new JLabel("").getFont(); System.out.println(f.canDisplay('한')); // correctly shows "false"`