# Java - How to tell which fonts don't render?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, jcombobox

I have:

```
Font[] fonts = 
   java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
```

which I then want to render in a JComboBox with a custom renderer however I'm finding that some fonts don't render at all, or just look beyond terrible. Some also take like 100-200 pixels of height in the JComboBox, some weird fonts that I'm not at all familiar with. So for example the 4th item is unreadable and the 5th (the selected one in blue) is huge and displays no characters even if you scroll down.

[image]

***I looked at trying to remove the offending fonts but I can't find a way to do it other than whitelisting which is not ideal.***

The best articles I found are:

- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/javaben/archive/2008/01/of_fonts_and_ja.html
- [Determining in Java whether a particular font can render a particular character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551587/determining-in-java-whether-a-particular-font-can-render-a-particular-character)

but the second is really just how to check for a particular character and not terrible rendering overall.

I've also tried `getAvailableFontFamilyNames()`, and although this reduces the list, several badly rendered fonts still appear in the JComboBox. By badly rendered I mean invisible with tons of height. So trying `canDisplay('a')` or something like that also doesn't work because it still returns true;

Comment: *"I mean invisible with tons of height."*  A picture paints a thousand words.  Also for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Just added a screenshot. The code is just a loop through fonts of JLabel.setFont(fonts[x].deriveFont(14f)); So nothing special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no metric for "looking horrible", but you could draw the string you want into some off-screen buffer and see the rectangle size the string "occupies" under each font.

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524855/how-to-calculate-the-fonts-width) for how to do it.

this way you could render the same string with all fonts and thow out the ones that produce too small or too-large "rectangles" - that should do away with all those fonts that currently mess up your ui.

Comment: That's the solution I had come up with. It's not exactly ideal even if it mostly works. I was just hoping for a more proper solution for lack of better words.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier - once a font declares its capable of rendering all characters in a string, how else can you disqualify it besides letting it try? :-)

Comment: Hence why I'm asking ;) I don't have a good solution. It seems to me that the definition of is capable is pretty loose here. I am reverting to size checks, and canDisplay for a basic font. Not ideal but I don't see any other way :(

Comment: I put the final solution, I added an extra check with it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up using incorporates what radai did but also adds `canDisplay('a')` so that I ended up with:

```
private boolean isAcceptableFont(Font font)
{
    int fontHeight = getFontMetrics(font).getHeight(); 
    if(fontHeight > MAX_FONT_HEIGHT || fontHeight < MIN_FONT_HEIGHT)
        return false;

    if(getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth(TEST_STRING_FOR_FONT_WIDTH) <= MIN_FONT_WIDTH)
        return false;

    if(!font.canDisplay('a'))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Checking the size of the rendered fonts removed a lot of bad fonts, but there were still a few that rendered really poorly. Adding a check to see if they could display at least the character 'a' seems to have filtered the remaining bad fonts.

It's not ideal, but it filtered 99+% of fonts that didn't make sense.